# Prestashop 1.7: Can I use another database just for executing a side script?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have created a Prestashop website with a database N°1. For some reasons, I want to write a script, that I'll execute a few times and that will simply fill a database N°2 with some data. This script has nothing to do with my Prestashop website, but is part of the same project and then, must be hosted in the same server, and moreover must be present within the Prestashop website's files (under a module directory I've made).

My question is: is it possible to use this database N°2 (only for this script)? Can I use Prestashop's `Db.php` class to do it?

Don't hesitate to ask for more informations if I'm not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i am reading your post correctly you want to create two databases.

[image: a busy cat]

For example "prestashop_n1" and "prestashop_n2".

**prestashop_n1** contains all prestashop required tables.

**prestashop_n2** contains data extracted from **prestashop_n1**

In order to extracted data from **prestashop_n1** to **prestashop_n2** you could write a module. 
In this module you can create a database connection to database **prestashop_n2**

You can use PHP to copy data from **prestashop_n1** to **prestashop_n2**

Alternative you can add a cron-job to execute your script for copying data x times a day.